# Adding images to photoshop a4 template

Tags: vb.net

I received some new task and its completly new for me to create program which would loop through directory images and place them into photoshop At layout template. Around 10 pictures per a4 photoshop template so 5 rows and 2 columns. If the template is filled out then next a4 photoshop template will be created and again past 5x2 and again and agin till images are filled in. The problem is i have no idea how to achieve that. Can you advise me how to do that or give some samples?

Best regards,
coder

Comment: the way i see it, the project could be split into 2 parts: **a)** looping through directory images and retrieving the image data, **b)** adding them into photoshop template either by photoshop automation or directly editting photoshop template files. which part you need help with?

Comment: hmm do be honest i am not sure which of your b option should i pick in this case maybe i can tell more detailed pics have to be placed in a common sheet at a known position - your first invested in position a, b ​​second position c , d so up to 10 files . After filling the entire worksheet is to be saved as Adobe PDF with ZIP compression and then closed or cleaned , and the whole operation is repeated until the end of images

Comment: you misunderstood my question. which of the parts **a)** or **b)** you need help with? first of all, do you know how to perform part **a)** ?

Comment: yes part one is simple, the problem is when it comes to b :)

Comment: you could first of all loop through all the images and add them into a list of 2d arrays, and later on use the row/col index as the picture's x/y coords in the template. after your list of 2d arrays is ready, you can stick them into a template one by one, or create a large image for each 2d array and then stick it into the template. have a look [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10885/Reading-Adobe-Photoshop-images) how to read PSD files in .Net,v.net or c# its all the same as long as its in .Net

Comment: the problem is how to load images on psd file in 5x2 ;/

Comment: If all images are the same size then its rather simple. Are they? Or are you willing to change their aspect ratio? Will it be alright to leave blank spaces in the psd, or do you want to cover the whole sheet with pic data?

Comment: requestor said that: "that pasted images may not be modified in any way , scaled , you can not change the palette ( working on a common RGB or CMYK palette - configured in the script - and this means that all the images source and destination sheet will have the same range , resolution etc. )". Banana can you advice me how to achieve that?

Comment: Hmm... so he did not mention any requirements of filling the aheet fully, thats good. All you need to do is create a logical grid/table and stick the images in the aheet aligned to that grid. If i get some time ill create a snippet here with an illustration in JavaScript (thats the only lang stack overflow supports in a snippet)

Comment: a question though, if source and destination sheets must have same range, doesnt it mean that only one image can fit in a template? if he wants to fit 5x2 images in the template, then one of the two must be scaled, either sheet or image

Comment: if you could help -thanks. hmm good question think rather sheet than images as he mentioned that images cannot be resized or whatever, Why JS can it be in Visual basic .net?

Comment: i am trying to help. i dont know how to do it by heart, obviously if i did i would just show you how... :) i can show you the logic behind the process, and the algorithm that will fit the images into the destination sheet and for that JS is enough (and id do it in JS because stack overflow can run JS code and i can visually show you the process) and all you need to do is to handle the coding which is the easy part. im not sure if ill have time for it today though.

Comment: ok but then i would have to convert this JS to vb or? I dont have knowledge about JS. Let me know if you would have something to show. Thanks @Banana

Comment: hi Banana, have you prepared something already? regards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82225/discussion-between-stackuser-and-banana).

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i am just usually on my phone and not always have access to a pc.

Comment: hi Banana can we go on chat with this? Do you have something already?

Comment: Banana can you answer please?

Comment: Hi, im sorry i am on the mobile app and don't have access to pc at the moment. You should start doing a research about this meanwhile, once i am able to i will illustrate what needs to be done. The main idea is pretty simple, create a 2D arrays of 5x2 and fill with objects that will hold the image url, and its dimensions. And then, before you create the destination sheet for every 2d array, you need to add the widths of all pictures for every row of the array an and the largest row will determine the width of the destination sheet, and same for columns.

Comment: After you create the sheets using the combined widths/heights of the pics in the largest row/column, you simply stick the pics into the destination sheet uaing x,y coordinates of the sum of all pictures widths/heights before the current ine in the row/column

Comment: ok ill start doing research in either vbscript or js. Let me know when you got something (same from my side). Notice we need to put images and not paths on a4 photoshop.